# How an empty set is collapsed to a point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, dynamical-systems, homotopy-theory, morse-theory

In the original book of `Conley Index Theory`: [Isolated Invariant Sets and the Morse Index chp3.3, p6](https://docs.zoho.com/file/mb9ur6e4af9173fdd472a936d1d60f1da382b), Charles Conley mentioned that `Morse Index` of an isolated invariant set is defined as the homotopy equivalence of pointed spaces which is created by collapsing exit point set of isolated neighborhood to a point.

For a `source` critical point, its isolated neighborhood is an interval containing it, with two endpoints as the exit point set. So pointed 1-sphere is a representative of its Morse Index.

However, for a `sink` critical point, The exit point set is $\emptyset$. In the book ,$\emptyset$ is collapsed to a point to get a 2-points space, i.e. 0-sphere. How that happens?

Comment: The empty set is not a pointed space.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen No. But my question is how an empty set can be collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a definition that makes everything smoother. See the discussion here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118574/conley-index-for-isolated-invariant-sets-with-no-exit-points .

An index pair of a one dim sink is a pair of an interval (e.g. [-1,1]) and the empty set (no points are flowing outward). Then the Conley index is $([-1,1]/\emptyset,[\emptyset])$ which is $([-1,1]\cup \{*\},\{*\})$ as a pointed space. Note that this is homotopy equivalent to a space with two points, which is the $0$-sphere.

Comment: Then why 1-dim sink's Morse Index is 0-sphere? Another definition?

Comment: Do you mean $[-1,1]$ is homotopy equivalent to one point, and $\{*\}$ homotopy equivalent to another point?

Comment: More or less. The spaces are homotopy equivalent as pointed spaces